# Laravel 5.5 with DataTables: ajax request makes the view.blade disappear

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm starting to learn the laravel framework, so I'm trying to build a simple app with dataTables.

I'm trying to follow some tutorials using Yajra\Datatables\Datatables.

The problem is: When I go to the page where the table is, the view disappears, and it shows only the data in ajax request, like a print_r() function.

I'm tried different tutorials and even changed from xampp to homestead but the result is always the same.

My code:

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::resource('/pages/show_asos', 'ShowAsosController');
Route::get('/pages/show_asos', 'ShowAsosController@task')- >name('datatables.data');
```

**Controller: App/Http/Controllers/ShowAsosController**

```
public function create()
{
   return view('/pages/show_asos');
}

public function task() 
{

   $asos = Asos::select(['id', 'name', 'admission', 'function', 
   'last_exam', 'next_exam']);
   return DataTables::of($asos)->make(true);
}
```

**Model: /app/Asos.php**

```
class Asos extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','admission','function','last_exam', 'next_exam'];
    protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'update_at'];
    protected $table = 'asos';
}
```

**resources/pages/show_asos.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row bg-title">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h4 class="page-title">Controle de Exames Periódicos</h4>
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">

                    </ol>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="white-box">
                        <table id="asos-table" class="datatable mdl-data-table dataTable" cellspacing="0"
                               width="100%" role="grid" style="width: 100%;">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Nome</th>
                                <th>Admissão</th>
                                <th>Função</th>
                                <th>Último Exame</th>
                                <th>Próximo Exame</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- row -->

        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    @push('custom-scripts')
        <script src="{{ asset('js/asos.js') }}"></script>
    @endpush
@stop
```

In the main view.blade I have:

```
@stack('custom-scripts')
```

**JS: /public/js/asos.js**

```
$('#asos-table').DataTable({
            "language": {
                "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix": "",
                "sInfoThousands": ".",
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
                "sProcessing": "Processando...",
                "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sNext": "Próximo",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                    "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                    "sLast": "Último"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
                }
            },
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{!! route('datatables.data') !!}",
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                {data: 'admission', name: 'admission'},
                {data: 'function', name: 'function'},
                {data: 'last_exam', name: 'last_exam'},
                {data: 'next_exam', name: 'next_exam'},
            ],
    });
```

This is supposed to be what the view should look like:

[view without ajax request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM10p.png)

And now, what appears on the screen:

[view with ajax request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o94lq.png)

**UPDATE**: For now I gave up using Yajra\Datatables\Datatables and ajax. If someone figure out what I am doing wrong, I'll try it again.

So I'm using this code below:

```
//Controller
$asos = Asos::all();
return view ( '/pages/show_asos' )->withData ( $asos );

//View
@foreach($data as $key => $item)
    <tr class="item{{$item->id}}">
    <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->admission}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->function}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->last_exam}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->next_exam}}</td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

I do not know the cons of using this method, but it's working.

Answer (score 2):

Since your ajax source is a url use this syntax:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
   "url": {the_url}
    ......
  }}
 );
```

source: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not work. It seems that the change has had no effect, I believe because neither the html file nor the js file are being loaded. Analyzing the answers of the chrome network seems that the problem is in this line: `Route::get('/pages/show_asos', 'ShowAsosController@task')- >name('datatables.data');`. Without this line, the view (blade.php) and js are loaded normally. I'll search more, but without much hope.
Thanks!!